# Overriding YAML frontmatter variables from Liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I would like my outermost Liquid template file to reference a JavaScript file only when the page requires it. I created a page variable, `page.slideshow`, which controls this:

default.html:

```
{% if page.slideshow %}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/slideshow.js"></script>
{% endif %}
```

Now I have a template that "inherits" from default.html, which allows the page to specify in its YAML frontmatter a list of images (`page.images`). Only when this list has more than one element do I want slideshow.js to be included in the page.

My attempt at this looks something like:

other.html

```
---
layout: default
---
{% assign imagecount = page.images | size %}
{% if imagecount > 1 %}
  {% assign page.slideshow = true %}
{% endif %}
```

However, this does not seem to affect the rendering of default.html, because the script tag is not included in the final page.

As a workaround, I can modify the frontmatter of each page that lists multiple images to explicitly set `slideshow: Yes`, or change default.html to check `page.slideshow or (page.images | size) > 0` but I'd prefer to structure it closer to what I attempted above.

Comment: has this been solved on your end?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a play about and you can't really do it the way you've suggested. It seems page variables just cant be modified once they're set. You might be able to set it with Jekyll plugins, but that's a whole other thing.

The cleanest way I have found to do it is to put all the logic in your main, outermost template.

```
{% assign imageCount = page.images | size %}
{% if page.slideshow or imageCount > 1 %}
    {{ page.images | size }}
    <script src="/js/slideshow.js"></script>
{% endif %}
```